# Проблема с загрузкой больших проектов в netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

Добрый день.

Пишу на php и в качестве ide использую netbeans (раньше долгое время использовал другую ide), проблема заключаеться в том,что когда создаю новый удаленный проект (проект большой) и netbeans начинает выкачивать файлы, то сначала всё нормально но потом он просто "обрываеться" и скачивает не весь проект.

Была идея скачать весь проект по ftp/ssh и потом закинуть в папку с проектом, но тогда будет ли нормально работать синхронизация с файлами проекта на сервере?

Comment: а вы прям на сервере разрабатываете ? используйте git например или mercurial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

да, лучше использовать какоуюто систему контроля версий, git, svn, mercurial
можно воспользоваться сервисами, которые это предоставляют, типа github или bitbucket. Во втором можно спокойно приватные репозиртории делать. можно свой сервер поднять.
на конечный сервер заливать можно либо вручную либо по крону -- как удобнее.